# How to eliminate extra values from query string parameter?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, cross-browser

I am developing a site which displays data from DB and show in grid to the user's and then there are few filters like Employee Type, Pay Grade e.t.c.

The requirement is that user should be able to share the filtered results via copying the URL and sending it someone, hence I used Form.Get method to allow values to pass via query string to the Action Method.

Everything works well just the URL append the values for empty check boxes as well in the URL for e.g Employee type have 3 checkboxes class A, class B and class C, lets say user has checked only class A, the URL that is generated is : http://sitename.com/?classA=true&classB=false&classC=false.

Is there a way I can eliminate these param's from the QS, Since I have been asked to replace Country dropdown with check-boxes so that user can combine the search, this way the URL will keep appending for all non selected countries as well, and I'll have iterate over each value manually to filter records in the backend.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I would hash the query string, lets say with MD5. This way you dont need to bother about the length of the url no matter how many parameters you have. for this example your url will look like this: http://sitename.com?filter=69c5bb44363b87e0c604e88dc45fca15

Comment: You can try to build and execute the url manually in jvascript.

Comment: @NatiDobkin : Not sure if its there in C#/asp.net

Comment: What i mean that after you are getting the query string you want for the filter you can hash it, there are various options to hash a string, I just gave an sample of a popular algorithm that has implementation in .net MD5 - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.md5(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

well... im not very famliliar wif c#
but HtmlInputCheckBox Class could do it for you...

or just write some short script with language u like like

```
if(value = false): cut the "&key=value" < (string) pair off
goto next
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much idea about c# but this is how it is done in PHP. I am sure you will find similar way to do this in C#.

You can define keys in query strings if you need to pass multiple values for it:

?key[]=value1&key[]=value2&key[]=valueN

In your case, if classA and classB are selected: 
http://sitename.com/?class[]=classA&class[]=classB

This is how PHP will read this:

```
$_GET["class"] = [
    0 => "classA",
    1 => "classB"
];
```

This way you will only have the selected parameters in the URL.

**Update**: Googled it for C#, not sure if it is the best way.

eg: http://sitename.com/?class=classA&class=classB

Taking the parameters as a string array:

```
public Example(string[] a)
{
     string first = a[0]; // classA
     string second = a[1]; // classB
     return View();
}
```